Is there standardized terminology for these derived rules to use as an alternative to the Deduction Theorem?
In studying a Hilbert-style proof system, I ended up coming up with the below derived rules (proved as metatheorems) which seem to form a useful alternative to using the Deduction Theorem.  For simplicity, I will write propositions with $\rightarrow$ being right-associative.  For reference, the axiom names I will use will be:
Ax1: $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$
Ax2: $(A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A\rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A\rightarrow C)$
Lift$_n$
\begin{align*}
B \\
\hline
A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow B
\end{align*}
Proof: By induction on $n$.  The base case $n=0$ is trivial.  I will also use the case $n=1$ in the general induction step, which is simple:

$B$: assumption
$B \rightarrow A_1 \rightarrow B$: Ax1
$A_1 \rightarrow B$: MP 2, 1

For the general induction step, assume Lift$_n$ is a valid derived rule.  Then the construction of Lift$_{n+1}$ is:

$B$: assumption
$A_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow B$: Lift$_n$ 1
$A_1 \rightarrow A_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow B$: Lift$_1$ 2 $\square$

I would tend to use this where $B$ is an axiom instantiation, and think of it as lifting the axiom $B$ into the context where we are assuming $A_1, \ldots, A_n$.
MP$_n$
\begin{align*}
A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \\
A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow B \\
\hline
A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow C
\end{align*}
Proof: By induction on $n$.  The base case $n=0$ is simply the regular modus ponens rule.  Now, for the induction step, assume MP$_n$ is a valid derived rule.  Then the construction of MP$_{n+1}$ is:

$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots A_n \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$: assumption
$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots A_n \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow B$: assumption
$(A_{n+1} \rightarrow B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A_{n+1}\rightarrow B) \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow C$: Ax2
$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow (A_{n+1} \rightarrow B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A_{n+1} \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow C$: Lift$_n$ 3
$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow (A_{n+1} \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow C$: MP$_n$ 4, 1
$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow C$: MP$_n$ 5, 2 $\square$

I think of this as being "modus ponens but with $n$ hypotheses prepended on each proposition involved".
Assump$_{k,n}$ for $1\le k\le n$
\begin{align*}
\hline A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_k
\end{align*}
Proof: By induction on $k$.  The base case $k=1$ actually ends up being the most interesting case, and is proved by induction on $n$.  In this subproof, the base case $n=1$ is the identity tautology $A_1 \rightarrow A_1$; I will not bother to repeat the standard proof of that tautology here.  For the inductive step, suppose Assump$_{1,n}$ is a valid derived rule.  Then the construction of Assump$_{1,n+1}$ will be:

$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_1$: Assump$_{1,n}$
$A_1 \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow A_1$: Ax1
$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_1 \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow A_1$: Lift$_n$ 2
$A_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_{n+1} \rightarrow A_1$: MP$_n$ 3, 1

That completes the proof for $k=1$.  Now, for the inductive step in the outer proof by induction on $k$: suppose Assump$_{k,n}$ is a valid proof rule for all $n$.  Then for any $n \ge k+1$, the construction of Assump$_{k+1,n}$ will be:

$A_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_{k+1}$: Assump$_{k,n-1}$
$A_1 \rightarrow A_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow A_{k+1}$: Lift$_1$ 1 $\square$

The interpretation of this one is clear: it corresponds to reiterating assumption number $k$ out of $n$.

Now to give an example of how I would use these derived rules, let me prove the tautology $(A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow C$, which is a typical example of an identity which is easy to prove using the Deduction Theorem but painful to prove directly in a Hilbert proof system.  With my derived rules, the proof is similarly simple:

$(A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$: Assump$_{1,3}$
$(A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow A$: Assump$_{3,3}$
$(A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$: MP$_3$ 1, 2
$(A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow B$: Assump$_{2,3}$
$(A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow C$: MP$_3$ 3, 4 $\square$

So, the idea is that I just take the natural proof of $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C, B, A \vdash C$ and prepend the three assumptions on each step.  (And yes, it does turn out to be possible to shorten the proof a bit since step 3 happens to be an instance of Assump$_{1,2}$, or more directly of Ax1.  I was consciously avoiding such optimizations to make the general application method clearer.)

Anyway, this seems straightforward enough that I can't have been the first person to discover this method.  I was wondering if there is more standardized terminology for these derived rules.  Also, maybe if you have an introductory-level reference using this method, that would be interesting to see.

Suppose that the logic I wanted to investigate today only has 7 propositional variables.  But, your system has 'n' propositional variables?  I don't have as many variables as the English alphabet from 'a' to 'n', nor do I have as many propositional variables as natural numbers.  The Deduction Meta-Theorem could get called variable conservative.  Any deduction made will have exactly as many variables as the axiomatic proof it corresponds to.  Perhaps, I'm wrong, but I'm suspicious that these rules are similarly variable conservative. So, I'm not sure that they are an equivalent alternative.

The $A_1, \ldots, A_n, B, C$ etc. in those rules are not necessarily distinct propositional variables, but placeholders for propositional formulas (just as $A,B,C$ are placeholders for formulas in Ax1 and Ax2).  None of the derived rules require introducing any new atomic propositional variables.

I don't think you can prove your Lift $_n$ from the degenerate or specialized wff  (A→(A→A)).  Given that you cannot, then you necessarily need at least two necessarily distinct propositional variables for Lift $_n$ to work.  Also, axiom 1 in it's full generality implies that the number of distinct variables can always increase from antecedent to consequent, given that there exists more possible variables in the vocabulary than we had in the antecedent.

One instance of Lift$_2$ for example, operating on the instance of Ax1 $A\rightarrow A\rightarrow A$, would be $((A\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (A\rightarrow A\rightarrow A)$.  And that can in fact be proved with all steps only using a single propositional variable.

CCCaaaCCaCaCaaCaCaa can get proved from CaCba, since CCCaaaCCaCaCaaCaCaa is an instance of CxCyCaCba.  It takes only two detachments and some substitution.  Why use Lift$_n$ for something so simple, especially since detachment involves less assumption, apparently, than the inductive assumption to prove Lift$_n$?

What do you mean by "detachment"?  If by that you mean the derived rule I call Lift$_1$ then yes, that's simple, and yes, Lift$_n$ is just applying that $n$ times (but induction/recursion is just a more formal way of making arguments involving the informal "repeat $n$ times").  And I found it useful to give a name to it to fit it into the rest of the framework and the alternative way of doing things.

And maybe I should have put it in the question, but the way I see the difference from the Deduction Theorem approach is -- the Deduction Theorem involves taking "taking apart a proof, modifying each part, and then reassembling" whereas this approach allows you to build up a proof using "stock building blocks" which are each just a fixed sequence of operations of fixed type, and once you've stuck some of the blocks together there's no need to disassemble and reassemble them later on.

By 'detachment', in this context, I mean the use of modus ponens.  The Deduction Theorem when applied doesn't take apart a proof and reassemble a proof.  It takes a deduction and then produces a formal proof from the primitive rules of inference.  To compare your approach thoroughly, you would need to compare how long using what you have to produce formal proofs from the primitive rules of inference ends up to use the algorithm implied by the deduction metatheorem.  But, it will still hold that your approach is not variable or placeholder conservative, while the deduction metatheorem is.

How about: Suppose we can infer from $P$ is true that $Q$ is true, i.e. it cannot be the case that both $P$ is true and $Q$ is false? As a convenient abbreviation, instead of $\neg(P\land \neg Q)$
we can simply write, $P\implies Q$.
